# Remove duplicate rows when using CASE WHEN statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently generating a table which converts the rows value to the new column, the following is my code:

```
SELECT ref_no,
    (CASE WHEN code = 1 THEN code END) AS 'count_1',
    (CASE WHEN code = 2 THEN code END) AS 'count_2',
    (CASE WHEN code = 3 THEN code END) AS 'count_3',
    (CASE WHEN code = 4 THEN code END) AS 'count_4',
    (CASE WHEN code = 5 THEN code END) AS 'count_5',
    (CASE WHEN code = 6 THEN code END) AS 'count_6'
FROM data"
```

The output is:

[image]

However, I needs those duplicated rows to be combined, is there any way to do? I don't need to sum up those values as there is no overlap among them.

I've tried with `group by` but it does not work as expected:

[image]

My expected out put is like:

```
ref   c_1  c_2  c_3  c_4  c_5  c_6
1     1     2    3    -    -    -
```

This shows adding `ORDER BY` clause does not work in my context.
[image]

Updated: complete query in sqldf

[image]

Comment: My answer will give you back your expected output

Comment: @sagi Thank you, but I think the order of ref_no looks weird (like the second screenshot I posted above), is there any way to keep the original order for ref_no (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...). Add "order by" at the end of code seems not work properly.

Comment: The order would look wierd if you won't order it, I've updated the answer to include order by clause. Anyways, The answer should work perfectly according to your examples.

Comment: The last screenshot shows where I implemented the ORDER BY clause, I used ORDER BY clause in sqldf with R for simple queries before, it worked, but I don't know why it does not work in this context.

Comment: Please show the entire query in sqldf , and what do you mean by not work properly? you've got an error?

Comment: I've updated with entire screenshot, not working just means it does not actually order the IDs, there is no error.

Comment: Oh, of course it won't order by .. the fact that test_Table2 got ordered values doesn't means when you select from it it will come out ordered.. I'm not familiar with this View(test_table2) syntax but you need to order it when you view it each time! The query is fine and the results are fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: YES

By using GROUP BY and MAX like this:

```
SELECT ref_no,
    max(CASE WHEN code = 1 THEN code END) AS 'count_1',
    max(CASE WHEN code = 2 THEN code END) AS 'count_2',
    max(CASE WHEN code = 3 THEN code END) AS 'count_3',
    max(CASE WHEN code = 4 THEN code END) AS 'count_4',
    max(CASE WHEN code = 5 THEN code END) AS 'count_5',
    max(CASE WHEN code = 6 THEN code END) AS 'count_6'
FROM data
GROUP BY ref_no
ORDER BY ref_no
```

Comment: Use "ORDER BY ref_no" seems not working for me, I am actually using sqldf to embed SQL code in R environment, does that matter?

Comment: Where did you implement the order by? I've updated the answer try it.

Comment: And I don't know if that matter, but this code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would either be to use GROUP BY or a PIVOT function.

GROUP BY example below:

```
SELECT ref_no,
    sum(CASE WHEN code = 1 THEN code ELSE 0 END) AS 'count_1',
    sum(CASE WHEN code = 2 THEN code ELSE 0 END) AS 'count_2',
    sum(CASE WHEN code = 3 THEN code ELSE 0 END) AS 'count_3',
    sum(CASE WHEN code = 4 THEN code ELSE 0 END) AS 'count_4',
    sum(CASE WHEN code = 5 THEN code ELSE 0 END) AS 'count_5',
    sum(CASE WHEN code = 6 THEN code ELSE 0 END) AS 'count_6'
FROM data
GROUP BY ref_no
```

A really long way of doing this using your existing code and a CTE table:

```
WITH results as (
SELECT ref_no,
    (CASE WHEN code = 1 THEN code END) AS 'count_1',
    (CASE WHEN code = 2 THEN code END) AS 'count_2',
    (CASE WHEN code = 3 THEN code END) AS 'count_3',
    (CASE WHEN code = 4 THEN code END) AS 'count_4',
    (CASE WHEN code = 5 THEN code END) AS 'count_5',
    (CASE WHEN code = 6 THEN code END) AS 'count_6'
FROM data) 

SELECT 
    ref_no
  , sum(coalesce(count_1),0)  -- for sum
  , max(coalesce(count_1),0)  -- for just the highest value
  -- Repeat for other ones 
FROM
  results
GROUP BY
  ref_no
```

Comment: Sorry I've signed the confidential agreement for this database, I can briefly describe: there are above 20 columns from "data" table and there are three entries with "ref_no = 1". All other columns for duplicated ref_no are exactly the same except the different "code" column (with 1, 2, 3), I wish to create a new table converting those into new columns and combine duplicated IDs.

Comment: It looks like your field ref_no is a text field, you will need to convert to a number to order 'properly', but this will remove the value with the '* ...' in your screenshots.

Comment: I actually did not have that row in original table... I think R did funky stuff when I executed the query, I can successfully perform ORDER BY ref_id in original table.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`PIVOT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) for this

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT ref_no, code FROM data
) data
PIVOT (
  max(code) FOR code IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6])
) pivoted
```

Comment: Thank you, but I do not wish to sum them up, and just need to display them in the same row.

Comment: @YangXia What happens with duplicates? E.g. `(8, 3)`?